# Установка полей у правых и левых страниц для печати, используя @media print

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Для печати страниц заданы такие правила:

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm;
}

@page :right {
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-right: 1.5cm;
}

@page :left {
    margin-left: 1.5cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: правила для `:left` и для `:right` будут действовать только, если установлена двусторонняя печать?

Если установлена односторонняя печать, будут действовать правила для `:left` или общие для `@page`?

Нужно ли вообще задавать общие правила, если заданы правила для `:left` и `:right`?